# Elasticsearch Scroll Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, scroll

I'm running an ES cluster with 8 shards and I'm using the java scroll api.

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = elasticsearchClient.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
        .setScroll("60000") // 1 mn
        .setQuery(query)
        .setSize(20) // 20 hits per shard
        .get();
```

When using a plain matchAll query, the number of results returned by each scroll iteration is correct (8*20).

But when I use a filtered query instead, I only get 20 results back. Per the documentation I was expecting 8*20.

I've tried to bypass the java api and to directly submit my JSON queries using the REST endpoints, but I still got 20 results back per scroll interation.

Any idea ?

Comment: I read the same thing in the configuration. I doubled checked results I have in one of my projects. There it seems to work. I do not use the setTypes though. What is the query you are executing? I use a match_all query.

Comment: You pointed something right. It comes from the query type. With a matchAll query the number of results is correct but not with a filtered query. I edited the question.

Comment: Is the index configured such that all shards have this index?